# Getting mutilple touch end events javascript

Tags: javascript, touch

I am using drag and drop between li of ul.
Code is working fine for desktop version.

```
<ul>
 <li> A </li>
 <li> A </li>
 <li> C </li>
 <li> D </li>
 <li> E </li>
</ul>
```

But for mobile version i am getting mutiple touch ends

```
li.addEventListener('touchstart', touchStart);
li.addEventListener('touchmove', touchMove);
li.addEventListener('touchend', touchEnd);
```

[image]

That's why i am unable to get correct element where i am dropping at.
How to get correct last touch element in mobiles?

Answer (score 1):

Post how you add event listeners to li elements. And consider below code

```js
var li=document.querySelectorAll('li');
 
 for(var i=0;i<li.length; i++){

   li[i].addEventListener('touchstart', function(e){
   console.log('Start '+e.target.id);
   });
 
  li[i].addEventListener('touchmove', function(e){
   console.log('Move '+e.target.id);
   });

  li[i].addEventListener('touchend', function(e){
   console.log('End '+e.target.id);
   });   
 }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li  id='li1'>One</li>
  <li id='li2'>Two</li>
  <li id='li3'>Three</li>
  <li id='li4'>Four</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: how does this code let me know, which was the last touch element